# raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) TimeoutException: Message:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

im new to python and selenium in general and i was trying an example i saw in youtube. this is the code example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest 

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

def test_Login(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
    driver = self.driver
    facebookUsername = "xxxxxxxx"
    facebookPassword = "xxxxxxxx"

    emailFieldId="email"
    passFieldId ="pass"
    loginButtonXpath="//input[@value='Log in']"
    fbLogoXpath = "(//a[contains(@href,'logo')])[1]"

    emailFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldId))
    passFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(passFieldId))
    loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(loginButtonXpath))

    emailFieldElement.clear()
    emailFieldElement.send_keys(facebookUsername)
    passFieldElement.clear()
    passFieldElement.send_keys(facebookPassword)
    loginButtonElement.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(lambda driver:     driver.find_element_by_id(fbLogoXpath))
def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

when i run the code it enters to facebook, but stops and gives me this error.

```
ERROR: test_Login (__main__.LoginTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facebot.py", line 25, in test_Login
    loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(loginButtonXpath))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 76, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///c:/users/ale/appdata/local/temp/tmpmle1b1/extensions/fxdriv
er@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10667)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///c:/users/ale/appdata/local/temp/tmpmle1b1/extensions/fxdriver@google
code.com/components/driver-component.js:10676)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/ale/appdata/local/temp/tmpmle1b1/extensions/fxdrive
r@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12643)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/ale/appdata/local/temp/tmpmle1b1/extensions/fxdriver@
googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12648)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/ale/appdata/local/temp/tmpmle1b1/extensions/fxdriver@googlec
ode.com/components/command-processor.js:12590)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 16.262s
```

i have tried fixing it by looking at youtube, but im stuck and dont know what could it be.

Comment: It looks like it timed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, the timeout value is too small, increase it. Plus, you can define the `WebDriverWait` instance only once and reuse:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

emailFieldElement = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldId))
passFieldElement = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(passFieldId))
loginButtonElement = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))
```

Also, note that you should use `find_element_by_xpath()` instead of `find_element_by_id()` when locating the "Log In" button.

Comment: thanks for your reply, did this but it still gets me the same error.

Comment: @2one2 got it, updated the answer. I think this would be solved now. Thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked, i changed the id with the xpath and used find_element_by_xpath, but can i ask why shouldnt i use find element by id?

Comment: does that error means that selenium didnt find the input boxes so it terminated itself?

Comment: @2one2 the problem was when you were locating the "Log In" button, passing an XPath expression into `find_element_by_id()`. There is no element with id="//input[@value='Log in']" on the page.

Comment: yea, it was "entrar" since im logging in spanish.

Comment: Selenium is such an arcane practise. For this reason, I'm grateful for posts like this one.