# How can I copy the text of a td with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I try to copy the text that is inside a td class:

```
<td align="left" colspan="3">7707304</td>
```

And I want to get the number: `7707304`
In the following way I try to copy it:

```
texto = driver.findElement(By.id("//*[@colspan='3']")).getText()
print(texto)
```

But I get a error.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks very much.

Comment: have you tried `.text` instead of `getText()`?

Comment: Yes, I did .text()

Comment: its not a function its just .text

Comment: I try and get this: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: you might have to wait till the page loads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643418/raise-timeoutexceptionmessage-screen-stacktrace-timeoutexception-message

Comment: The page loads correctly, I even wait a bit:
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)

Answer (score 0):

The solve is:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@colspan='3']")
visibleText = element.text
```